# Make CSS compatible with non-Firefox browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have this css code for an select tag

```
.sele {
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform:scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0.75; 
    margin: 0 10px 5px 0; 
}
.sele:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
    -o-transform:scale(1.1);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; 
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

It is working well on Mozilla Firefox but has no effect on chrome or Internet explorer

Comment: Also use non-prefixed version...

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would advice you to have a look into [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-never-type-a-vendor-prefix-again/)

That's weird... i have tested your code on 5 browsers ( Chrome, Mozilla , Safari , Opera , IE ) and only IE had a problem with the transform which you can solve it by adding the code below:

```
transform: scale(2,4);
```

Check the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zvRRx/3/)

Edit: I don't think you can use this directly on a select option, but you have wrap the select tag within a div and apply that to the div.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zvRRx/4/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot but actually this code is for <select> tag and i have used it at http://www.thats.e.gy/pointer/ and its not working in chrome can you please help me with this ?

Comment: @user25411787 Edited my answer after seeing your comment. Does this help?

Comment: I want it to work exactly as it does in firefox and don't want <select> to zoom only <option> needs to be zoomed.